# Unlocking Pistol Swords in Asassion's Creed IV: Black Flag

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I know I need to complete the Assasination Contracts to unlock the pistol swords, but do I have to complete them perfectly? I noticed some of these missions have additional rewards for "stay our of combat", do I need to get those rewards to be able to unlock the swords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to "100% perfect" the assassination missions. **The requirement for unlocking the pistol swords is simply "complete all assassination missions".**

I was not sure if I was remembering this correctly, but confirmed this with [the IGN guide](http://au.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/Pistol_Swords), and [the Assassin Creed Wikia](http://au.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/Pistol_Swords).

The sub-objectives, IIRC, are simply a means to earn more reward. They may, however, count towards 100% synchronisation.